# How can I detect URL Not Found Error in php curl?

Tags: php, url, curl, http-status-code-404, php-curl

How can I detect this error using php curl? curl return success even if the URL does not exist.

```
Not Found
The requested URL /foo/index.php/items/edit was not found on this server.
```

My code

```
$post_fields = array('info' => json_encode($fields));
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($post_fields));
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post_fields);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE,'application/x-www-form-urlencoded charset=utf-8');

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    echo $result;

    if(curl_error($ch)){
        $result = curl_error($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $result;
    }else{
        curl_close($ch);
        return json_decode($result,true);

    }
```

Comment: $http_status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); check it if it is 404 or something else

Comment: url not found should return a 404 error, so you should check on the headers of the response.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use this to get HTTP status code:

```
$code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
```

If 404, it means the request URL cannot be found.

Note: remember to issue this line before `curl_close($ch);`

Comment: its working thanks..but Can I assuem that all status codes other than 200 is a failure?

Comment: Yes, but you should look into what server responses to you too. 200 only means the request is successful.